# Extended Partition (Partition 4) does not start on physical sector boundary for a dual boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have recently installed both windows and linux (64 bits). Upon typing sudo fdisk -l I get the out put below.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006ef1e


 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   307202047   153497600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       307202048   716802047   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       716804094   976771071   129983489    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       716804096   965054463   124125184   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       965056512   976771071     5857280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I am using applications such as Netbeans, Eclipse etc in linux so I am wondering if the

message above can pose a problem. When I first saw the message, I re-performed an Installation of the linux but it didn't solve the problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not critical, you actually never write to the extended partition, only the logical partitions inside the extended. So every other partition should be divisible by 8 to be correct. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-on-4kb-sector-disks/ and:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html